# FATAL EXCEPTION: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting this null pointer exception for the below piece of code.

I am trying to set the listview with previously selected values.

Please do help.

Code:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Brand_list.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,Brand_List_Temp);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    Log.i("Adapter set", "Yes");
    if(checkedlistprev.isEmpty()==false){

        for(int j=0;j<checkedlistprev.size();j++){
            int pos=adapter.getPosition(checkedlistprev.get(j));
            listView.setSelection(pos);
        }

    }
```

Error Log:

```
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012): Process: test.dsi.XXXXX, PID: 13012
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.dsi.decathnavigation/test.dsi.XXXXX.Brand_list}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at test.dsi.decathnavigation.Brand_list.onCreate(Brand_list.java:136)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
08-07 17:52:20.674: E/AndroidRuntime(13012):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: some variable is null... which is line 163 in Brand_list and show your full code..

Comment: What is `checkedlistprev`? Has it been initialized?

Comment: A `NullPointerException` pretty much always means the same thing.  You're trying to use an object which is `null` at runtime.  When you debug this, which object is `null`?

Comment: You probably also shouldn't be running this adapter code in the onCreate(); but instead onResume  OnCreate runs before the activity comes into view, and if you do too much heavy lifting it will only slow down the interaction of getting to said activity

Comment: checkedlistprev is null for the first time... how do i handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't have to check if its empty before the for loop.. but you should check to make sure its not null

```
if(checkedlistprev==null){

       checkedlistprev = new ArrayList<int>();// or what ever it is

}

for(int j=0;j<checkedlistprev.size();j++){
            int pos=adapter.getPosition(checkedlistprev.get(j));
            listView.setSelection(pos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked.. I am able to get the positions right.. But I am not able to highlight them in the listview.. How can i do it?

Comment: Please be more specific.. Any highlighting etc, you would probably do in your adapter.. your question is not clear.. please accept this answer for fixing the crash and start a new question with your highlighting issue